# Topology Metrics

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, and suppose $d$ is a metric on $X$. Let $$\mathcal{B} = \{B(x,\epsilon) : x \in X,\space \epsilon > 0\}$$ be the set of open balls where $$B(x,\epsilon) = \{y \in X, \space d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$$

(1) Prove that B is a base for X.

(2) Let $$\mathcal{C} = \left\{B\left(x,\frac{1}{n}\right) : x \in X,\space n \in \Bbb{N}\right\}$$ 
Prove that the topology generated by $\mathcal{C}$ is the same as the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$.

(1) Seems pretty straight forward geometrically. But mathematically I am having some trouble formalizing a proof.

(2) Also seems straight forward geometrically.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3):

$1.)$ Let $U \subset X$ be open. Then for any $x \in U$ there is an open ball in $\mathcal{B}$ of radius $\epsilon_x$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_x) \subset U$. We can use this criteria to form a collection of open balls, $\left\{B(x,\epsilon_x) \right\}_{x \in U}$.

Now show that $$\bigcup_{x \in U}B(x,\epsilon_x) =U$$ and you will have shown that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $X$.

$2.)$ **Hint:** Use what you know about part $1$ to complete part $2$, and remember that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.